# How to determine if exist transclude content in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Say you have a directive like below.

**Directive**

```
module.directive('person', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      header: '='
    },
    transclude:true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'

  };
});
```

**View**

```
  <person>
    .....
  </person>
```

I want to know if there is a way to know there exist transcluded html content in the `<person>`.

Thanks.

Comment: Not tried but you can use a css selector on the directive element object in link function to determine ng-transclude is present or not, and innerHTML to know if there is content

Comment: You need to use jquery to find if children has ng-transclude just as @Chandermani mentioned. $('person').find( '[ng-transclude]' )  or something

Comment: @Joe take a look at my answer

Comment: Sure, Thannks your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `link function` in directive for finding the child nodes like as shown below

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes)
      {
            var count = element.find('div')[0].children.length;
            var content = element.find('div')[0];
            console.log(content);
            console.log("Transcluded html content nodes:"+count);
      }
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nidhishkrishnan/akxp66wd/5/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
    <person>
        <input type="text" ng-model="user" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="place" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid"/>
    </person>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('person', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      header: '='
    },
    transclude:true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes){
        var count = element.find('div')[0].children.length;
        var content = element.find('div')[0];
        console.log(content);
        console.log("Transcluded html content nodes:"+count);
    }
  };
});

app.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {

});
```

**Output**

[image]