# Keep content of custom directive with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Usage:

```
<interactive-button id="test-button" class="grey" text="This is a test" icon-left="add">Hello World</interactive-button>
```

Output:

```
<div class="grey button ng-isolate-scope" id="test-button" text="This is a test" icon-left="add" icon-right="delete">
   <i ng-if="::iconLeft" class="icon kico add"></i>
   <span ng-if="::text" class="sentence ng-binding ng-scope">This is a test</span>
</div>
```

Directive module:

```
/**
 * Created by stephanbijzitter on 28/05/15.
 */
(function() {
    var directive_name = 'interactiveButton';
    var template_file = '/angularTemplates/interactive.button.template.html';
    var module = angular.module(directive_name, [template_file]);

    module.directive(directive_name, function() {
        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                text: '@',
                iconLeft: '@',
                iconRight: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: template_file
        };
    });

    angular.module(template_file, []).run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put(template_file,
            '<div class="button">\n' +
            '   <i ng-if="::iconLeft" class="icon kico {{::iconLeft}}"></i>\n' +
            '   <span ng-if="::text" class="sentence">{{text}}</span>\n' +
            '   <i ng-if="::iconRight" class="icon kico {{::iconRight}}"></i>\n' +
            '</div>'
        );
    }]);
}());
```

In the usage sample, you can see the `Hello World` between the opening and closing tags of the custom directive. I wish to be able to work with this content. I dislike having to use a `text=...` parameter in my directive.

Essentially, I want to remove the `text` parameter and replace it by whatever is between the directive's tags.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean.. You can get the element from the directive, why not call the .text() function on that? It will return the text that you have between your tags.

Comment: Check out transclusion: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: Awesome @SergiuParaschiv that works like a charm, if you want feel free to submit an answer and I will mark it as solved. Updated directive: https://gist.github.com/StephanBijzitter/b1b74906f5894512d6a6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [transclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude):

```
module.directive(directive_name, function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        translcude: true
        scope: {
            iconLeft: '@',
            iconRight: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: template_file
    };
});

angular.module(template_file, []).run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put(template_file,
        '<div class="button">\n' +
        '   <i ng-if="::iconLeft" class="icon kico {{::iconLeft}}"></i>\n' +
        '   <span class="sentence"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></span>\n' +
        '   <i ng-if="::iconRight" class="icon kico {{::iconRight}}"></i>\n' +
        '</div>'
    );
}]);


<interactive-button id="test-button" class="grey" icon-left="add">This is a test</interactive-button>
```

Comment: I like this, it keeps the code very clean and works as it should. There is one drawback, because the `ng-if` on the `span` element probably needs to be removed, unless there is a way to check if there is transcluded content?

Comment: Unfortunately for that you need to check the DOM yourself in the `link` function of the directive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173733/how-to-determine-if-exist-transclude-content-in-directive

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `link` to get the element, and if you have the element, you can do with it whatever you like. Like so:

```
module.directive(directive_name, function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            text: '@',
            iconLeft: '@',
            iconRight: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var yourText = element.text();
        },
        templateUrl: template_file
    };
});
```

I think this is what you are looking for. I didn't test the code, but it should be fine.

Comment: It seems that the content of `yourText` is correct, but assigning it to the scope and having it replaced `{{text}}` seems to be troublesome, as it only outputs `{{text}}` instead of its actual (new) value.